# Reading formatted numerical data to an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, input

I am using C++. I have a data file which looks like this with several thousand rows, where the first number is the number of rows.

```
1238
0.37 0.29 -1.00
1.34 -2.95 3.40
4.59 2.21 1.29
```

I would like to read it into a two dimensional array.

My code, which works is:

```
int main(){
    ifstream source("atoms.xyz");
    int N;
    source >> N;
    double atoms[N][3];
    int i = 0;
    for (;i < N; i++){
        int j = 0;
        for (;j < 3; j ++){
        source >> atoms[i][j];
    }
    }
}
```

Is this idiomatic ? Looking on other stack overflow answers most seem to use "getline" and other string handling functions, but this seems overcomplicated to me.

Comment: Firstly, I think codereview.stackexchange is a better place to post this. Secondly, what is the rationale behind declaring the `for` loop in the given manner, besides making the eyes bleed?

Comment: Your code should not compile, as N is not known at compile-time.

Comment: @oLen : That depends on the compiler. g++ with extensions allows VLAs, whereas MSVC doesn't.

Comment: This question looks like it might be a pretty good fit for [Code Review.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), provided that (a) you want _every aspect_ of your code reviewed, not just some, (b) your code is _already working_, and (c) you're asking for a review of _concrete, real code_, not abstract design (whether or not it's expressed as code). If you agree with all of those, please read about [what's on topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and, if your question fits that, delete it here and repost it on CR.

Comment: I will repost on code review. Thank you ! Am using g++ so no compile issues.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Code Review SE. There should be a painless option to move such questions TBH.

Comment: Possible duplicates: ["stackoverflow c++ read file matrix"](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+read+file+matrix&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).  In other words, search the internet before posting.

Answer (score 3):

First, using variable-length arrays in C++ is an extension, not a standard feature. When the number of entries is not known at compile time, using `std::vector` provides better portability.

If the number of atoms per line is fixed and is small, it is more idiomatic to "unroll" the inner loop, i.e. to write

```
source >> atoms[i][0] >> atoms[i][1] >> atoms[i][2];
```

instead of

```
for (;j < 3; j ++){
    source >> atoms[i][j];
```

Here is one way of rewriting this using `std::vector<T>` and an unrolled loop:

```
int n;
cin >> n;
vector<array<double,3>> atoms;
for (int i = 0 ; i != n ; i++) {
    array<double,3> data;
    cin >> data[0] >> data[1] >> data[2];
    atoms.push_back(data);
}
```

Note the use of `std::array` for the second "dimension". When the size of the dimension is known at compile time, this option is more economical, both in terms of memory size and cache friendliness.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/2tRcCx)